The variance of a band-limited Gaussian process out of correlation filter

Let $X(t)$ be a real Gaussian process of bandwidth $W$ and spectral density $N_0/2$. Let $\phi(t)$ be a orthonormal (in $L_2$ sense) function with bandwidth $W$.
Consider the correlator output $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(t)\phi(t)dt$, which is a random variable.

Can someone please help me to understand what is its variance? Is it $N_0/2$? Or $N_0W$?

Is this a homework problem? If so, can you please add the homework tag, and edit your question to explain how you've attempted to solve the problem and where you got stuck?
